# Удаление элементов из таблицы mysql

Tags: sql

Нужна ваша помощь. Я с помощью синтаксиса SQL пытаюсь удалять элементы таблицы. В таблице у меня было 5 элементов, и поле id у меня шло по-возрастанию и по-порядку. Однако при удалении предыдущих элементов id не изменяются. Например, в таблице были элементы из id 1,2,3,4,5. Удаляю второй и третий элемент, а я получаю 1,4,5. Как устранить данную проблему? Спасибо

Comment: Используете тип Sequence

Comment: Не нужно это исправлять. Значение Id обеспечивает целостность данных, а если вы будете менять текущие id на другие id, то можете получить различные проблемы. А если очень хочется, то нужно сделать UPDATE запрос и через него указать новые значения id. Или сделать новую таблицу с такими же полям, перенести в нее элементы из текущей таблицы, удалить текущую таблицу и новую назвать как старую. Но лучше так не делать и не трогать id :)

Comment: @gil9red, Хорошо, я понял. Однако меня интересует еще следующее: Если я создаю элементы таблицы с помощью, например Java (CRUD), и у меня там работает auto increment, и пробую удалить элемент определенный, у меня так же не восстановится список из id по-порядку. Это считается нормальным поведением работы?

Comment: @Halland это нормально.

Answer (score 2):

Воспринимайте ID не как "номер по порядку", а как "номер паспорта записи".

Было бы странно, если бы при смерти одного гражданина, другим пришлось бы менять паспорта и заново предоставлять информацию о новом своем номере паспорта во все учреждения, куда они хоть раз предоставляли свой паспорт.

Вот так и записи нет смысла менять свой ID, и уведомлять всех о том что он изменился.

Answer (score 1):

Весь принцип реляционных баз данных, в которые входит SQL, основывается на том, что записи в разных таблицах могут ссылаться на id записей в других таблицах. Например у нас есть таблица books где хранится информация о книгах, и таблица authors, где хранятся авторы. В каждой записи в таблице books в столбце author указан id из таблица authors. Таким образом, мы можем из любой записи о книге получить всю информацию об авторе этой книги по его id, или получить все книги, которые написал конкретный автор. Именно это и является причиной того, что id не меняют число при удалении промежуточных записей. ID - это не автоматическая нумерация количества, это уникальный номер записи, по которому в дальнейшем можно получить поля записи.